# How to compare 10-digit unix date with dd/mm/yyyy date format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list all the products between 01/01/2008 and 31/10/2008. The product entry date in mysql is entered in 10-digit format. This is the sql I tried but it's returning all the data from the table and ignoring the date comparison:

```
SELECT productid, productname
  FROM products
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '01/01/2008' and '31/12/2008'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The dates in your query are probably not being implicitly converted to DATETIME data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tips:

1. Take advantage of MySQL's native date formt.
2. Put the calculation in the constant part of the comparison.

Putting these together, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT productid, productname
  FROM products
 WHERE entry_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01')
```

Using the native date format means you don't have to play games with the formatting options. But in this query, the bigger win is from putting the calculation in to the constant part of the comparision. This is a win because MySQL only has to do the calculation once, not on every row it is looking at. This also means it can use the index on this field, if there is one.

BTW, I use queries just like this frequently.

(And I used '2009-01-01' at the end range to avoid an off-by-one error. (Unix timestamps are accurate to the second and date without a time turns into midnight. So your original comparison would have excluded December 31 from your resultset.)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems to work for me. I have 2 more questions:

- Why the date within UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01') cannot be in mm/dd/yyyy format?
- Is it ok just to pass the date and not time in UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01')?

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy is US-centric and ambiguous and can sometimes be mistaken for dd/mm/yyyy. yyyy-mm-dd is unambiguous, is an international standard and thus what MySQL defaults to. And it's okay to pass just the date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP; if it's missing, the time defaults to `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what datatype your ten digit entry_date is.

If it is a `DATETIME` type, you're making this harder than it needs to be.  Here's the query.

```
SELECT productid, productname
  FROM products
 WHERE entry_date >= str_to_date('01-01-2008', '%d-%m-%Y')
   AND entry_date < str_to_date('01-11-2008', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Notice that the `BETWEEN` operator is not suitable for `DATETIME` types. When you don't specify the time, the system assumes you mean midnight on the date you specified.  Therefore, you need to give the first day AFTER your chosen end date (in this case, your chosen end date was 31-Oct-2008, so you should use 1-Nov-2008). You then need to use `<` rather than `<=` for the top of your range, as shown.

If you don't have to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` data types, don't.  They're less flexible than ordinary `DATETIME` types.

If you don't mind specifying your dates in YYYY-MM-DD format it's even easier:

```
SELECT productid, productname
  FROM products
 WHERE entry_date >= '2008-01-01'
   AND entry_date < '2008-11-01'
```

Comment: entry_date is in ten-digit format such as 1542415245. staticsan's solution seems to work for me. Thanks for your reply.